# Assigning value to a new variable from existing column using for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to create a new time series variable where the data consists of 4 static variables and time series data across columns.
I need to get the values from each time series column against each year

```
A B    C    year  Del_0 Del_1 Del_2 Del_3 Del_4.....
1 abc  qwe  2012  1     2      3    4     5
1 abc  qwe  2013  3     5      3    6     8
1 def  qwe  2014  2     3      6    2     1
1 def  qwe  2013  12    23     21   45    43
```

I need to get the first value which is Del_0 for the latest year, Del_1 value against previous year and so on within each group of A,B and C.

I did an aggregate to get the max year for each class

```
  max_year<-     aggregate(newdata$Year,by=list(newdata$A,newdata$B,newdata$C),max)
```

I merged it back to original data

```
newdata1<-merge(x=newdata,y=max_year,by=c("A","B","C"),all=TRUE)

newdata1$diff=newdata1$max_yr-newdata1$Year#Calculating difference
```

I am trying to get the Del_0 value for the latest year using the difference value which would be 0 for the latest year within each group.

I am trying to use for loop.

```
for(i in 0:4){
df[[paste(i, 'AVG', sep="_")]]<-newdata1$Del[i]
}

final data would be
A B    C    year  Del_0 Del_1 Del_2 Del_3 Del_4.....Avg0 Avg1 Avg2 Avg3 Avg4
1 abc  qwe  2012  1     2      3    4     5                2
1 abc  qwe  2013  3     5      3    6     8         3
1 def  qwe  2013  12    23     21   45    43               23
1 def  qwe  2014  2     3      6    2     1         2
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this easily with `data.table`.  Get the column names that start with "Del" in the "newdata", ('i1'), remove the substring prefix until the `_` with `sub`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(newdata)`), grouped by 'A', 'B', and 'C', columns, and specifying the `.SDcols` as 'i1', we loop through the Subset of Data.table (`lapply(.SD, ...`)  and get the `max`, assign (`:=`) the output to new columns 'i.e. "Avg0", "Avg1" (created with `paste0`).

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- grep("^Del", names(newdata), value = TRUE)
i2 <- sub(".*_", "", i1)
setDT(newdata)[, paste0("Avg", i2) := lapply(.SD, max, na.rm = TRUE), 
            by = .(A, B, C), .SDcols = i1]
```

Comment: Thanks. But the average values are not populated. They are all NAs

Comment: @bnair If there are NA values i nthe original dataset, then use `na.rm=TRUE` (updated the post).  Also, check the `str(newdata)` to see if the 'Del' columns are `numeric` or not.